# Rails - Horizontal Transition from one view to the next

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to create a web app that has a similar feel to a mobile app. The idea is really like swiping your finger from one page to the next on a smartphone - The page just slides over on top of the current page, but you don't feel like it's loading an entirely new page.

I want to do this in my rails app, but I need to know where I should start looking - Is that javascript, is there something in rails or ruby that will give me that affect, etc. Where should I start my studying to learn how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a JavaScript question

You have a couple of options to implement this:

1. load your layout and the slides as partials, use JavaScript to slide between them
2. load your layout and the first slide as a partial, use JavaScript to slide to the next slide and load the slide contents using ajax

Comment: Cool - I'm just now getting into Javascript and it seems to be more and more useful everyday. I'll keep looking there, thanks for the tip.